# If v is harmonic conjugate of u, then the harmonic conjugate of $3u^2 − v^3$ is harmonic conjugate of

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, analytic-functions

Attempt:
I tried to use cr-equations,but integration becomes clumsy. Also, I tried to form another holomorphic function which have real part equal to $3u^2 − v^3$ using any other holomorphic functions, but was unable to do that.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Can you please tell us what you need exactly?

Comment: what is $(u+iv)^3.$  Note that you have an error, it should be $3u^2 v - v^3$

Comment: Question is this, If v is harmonic conjugate of u, then 3u^2 − v^3 is harmonic conjugate of, sorry for the vague statement above. Note: It is not equal to 3u2v−v3, which is simple enough to find.